# Remove row from Treelist kendo

Tags: events, kendo-ui, kendo-treelist

I would like to remove row from Treelist after click in button. I bind function in event "click: remove". Firstly , I choose a row and next try remove object from DataSource. And this point is not correct.

```
remove: function () {
                    var that = this;
                    if (this.isGridSelected) {
                        var arr = [];
                        arr = this.selectedRow.toJSON();//this line show selected row

                        this.roleDataSourcePrzypisane.remove(this.arr);//I think this row is wrong ...Remove no work
                        console.log(this.roleDataSourcePrzypisane);


                        this.set("roleDataSourcePrzypisane", this.roleDataSourcePrzypisane);

                    } else {
                        iwInfo('Please choose row', 'warning');
                    }


                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeRow(e) {
    var treelistCurrentInstance = $("#treelist").data("kendoTreeList");
    var currentRow = $(e).closest('tr');
    treelistCurrentInstance.removeRow(currentRow);
}
```

I have tried something similar, i'm taking reference of current row by instance of button and using removeRow method of kendo treelist.

Answer (score 0):

Assume a button control:

```
<button id="btn">Remove selected row</button>
```

The click event removes a **selected row** in the kendoUI jQuery TreeList control:

```
$("#btn").click(function()
{
    let Treelist = $("#treelist").data("kendoTreeList");
    let Row = Treelist.select();
    Treelist.removeRow(Row);
});
```

Ensure that the TreeList is editable, e.g. with:

```
"editable": true
```

in the TreeList creation definition, otherwise the .removeRow() method won't work.